# Peticiones de eliminación de usuarios duplicada(actualizada)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, ajax

estoy haciendo un CRUD con Laravel, AJAX y MySQL. El problema es que, a la hora de eliminar los registros, me pasa algo que no consigo entender. Cuando refresco la pagina, elimino un registro y todo va perfecto, sin embargo, al borrar el segundo, me vuelve a intentar borrar el primero (lo cual obviamente da un error 500) y el segundo lo hace bien, y asi sucesivamente con el tercer registro, cuarto, etc... Me intenta borrar todos los anteriores antes de ese.

Esta es la ventana modal del botón que llama a la función que elimina los registros:

```
<div id="delete-user" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Eliminar Usuario</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
        @csrf
      <p id="delete-user-txt"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" id="remove_btn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Petición AJAX que muestra la ventana modal y elimina los registros:

```
    function show_delete_form(id) {
        
        $.get('/admin/show-delete-form/' + id, function (user) {
        $("#delete-user-txt").html('¿Desea eliminar el usuario ' + user + '?');
        $('#delete-user').modal('toggle');
        })
        const token = $("input[name=_token]").val();
        $('#remove_btn').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let id_empty= id;
            console.log(id_empty);
            console.log('/admin/show-delete-form/' + id);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/delete-register",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    _token: token
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res == true) {
                        console.log(res);
                        id_empty= "";
                        $('#delete-user').modal('hide');
                        toastr.info('El registro fue eliminado correctamente',
                            'Eliminar Registro', {
                                timeout: 3000
                            });

                            $('#users_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                            


                    }  
                    if (res == "same_admin") {
                        toastr.warning('No puedes eliminarte a ti mismo', 'Eliminar Registro', {
                            timeout: 3000
                        });
                    }
                    if (res == false) {
                        toastr.warning('Ha ocurrido un error', 'Eliminar Registro', {
                            timeout: 3000
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
})
    }
```

La ruta control_panel que muestra la datatable:

```
   function control_panel(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        # code...

        $users = DB::table('users')->get('*');

        return DataTables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('edit', function ($edit) {
                $edit = '<td class="text-center"><a onclick="edit_user(' . $edit->id . ')">Editar</a></td>';
                return $edit;
            })
            ->addColumn('delete', function ($delete) {
                $delete = '<td class="text-center "><a onclick="show_delete_form(' . $delete->id . ')">Borrar</a></td>';
                return $delete;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['edit', 'delete'])
            ->make(true);
    }
    return view('admin.controlpanel');
}
```

La ruta delete_register que muestra la datatable:

```
   function delete_register(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
    
    if ($user->id == Auth::user()->id) {
        return response()->json("same_admin");
    } else {
        $user_delete = DB::delete('delete from users where id = ?', [$id]);
        
        if ($user_delete == 1) {
            return response()->json(true);
        } else {
            return response()->json(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: una pregunta ya identificaste si el evento se duplica en el javascript o cuando llega a tu php?

Comment: puedes remplazar esto: `$('#remove_btn').click(function(e){`
por esto: `$(document).off('click.req', '#remove_btn');
$(document).unbind('click.req', '#remove_btn');
$(document).on('click.req', '#remove_btn', function(e, xhr, settings){`

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿esto `console.log('/admin/show-delete-form/' + id);` muestra siempre en consola el `id` que debería borrarse realmente? No conozco Laravel, pero esta lógica aquí me parece al menos confusa: `$delete = '<td class="text-center "><a onclick="show_delete_form(' . $delete->id . ')">Borrar</a></td>';` ¿`$delete` es **al mismo tiempo** la cadena que estás construyendo y un objeto con una propiedad `id`? Yo pondría cada ID en un sitio del que lo pueda recuperar sin ningún riesgo (en el `value` del `button` por ejemplo), y lo recuperaría con `this`  en Javascript).

Comment: Además, no veo por qué haya que recargar la tabla cada vez ¿? Simplemente, puedes eliminar el elemento en el servidor, notificar al cliente cuando esto ocurra y quitar esa fila de la tabla. No tiene mucho sentido recargarla cada vez ¿no?

Comment: eso es necesario cuando trabajas con datatables.net para actualizar el cache de tabla... no es html plano.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso Buenas, he probado a poner el console.log function delete_register(Request $request)
{ y no me duplica los id.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso he probado el código que me has pasado y ahora funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias!! Me podrías explicar como funciona el código, te lo agradecería mucho ya que estoy aprendiendo ajax.

Answer (score 1):

tienes un problema con los eventos amarrados al DOM y tratas de hacer triger a un elemento agregado por jquery, eso no funciona y debes implementar la limpieza de eventos y la delegacion de eventos de jquery, tambien recomiendo agregarle un namespace al evento para diferenciarlos de otros.

puedes remplazar esto:

```
$('#remove_btn').click(function(e){
```

por esto:

```
$(document).off('click.req', '#remove_btn'); // limpieza de eventos con off
$(document).unbind('click.req', '#remove_btn'); // limpieza de eventos con unbind

$(document).on('click.req', '#remove_btn', function(e, xhr, settings){ // delegacion de eventos a document y uso de namespace de evento click.req
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @Angel si la rwspuesta soluciona el problema puedes marcarlo como resuelto